# The name "icon_font_generator" is not recognized as the name Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to generate svg icons for my project using icon_font_generator, so I made these steps:

1. flutter pub global activate icon_font_generator 4.0.0
2. set PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/Tools/flutter/.pub-cache/bin"
3. icon_font_generator --from=icons --class-name=Iconly --out-font=lib/src/icon_font/iconly.ttf --out-flutter=lib/src/widgets/icons.dart

but now I am getting the error

> The name "icon_font_generator" is not recognized as the name of a
> cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.

how can I solve it? I am using Windows OS. My flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1052])
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.6.5)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
[√] Network resources
```